# How to bind a Dictionary to DataSource of DataGridView

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagridview

I think that question is clear. I have a Dictionary instance and I want to bind it like DataSource of a DataGridView instance. Actually I can bind it straight this way:

```
Dictionary<string,string> d = new Dictionary<string,string>();
d.Add("1","test1");
d.Add("2","test2");
DataGridView v = new DataGridView();

v.DataSource = d;
```

But without any results.

Comment: A start would be to populate your `Dictionary`.

Comment: Your dictionary is empty!

Comment: Sorry mans, I repaired it already.

Comment: What's so wrong on this question guys that it has minus rate?? I'm confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the DataSource property. It only handles specific types (IList, IListSource etc.). So you cannot bind it to an IDictionary. So, this will work:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> d = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
d.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "2323"));
d.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "1112323"));

DataGridView v = new DataGridView();
v.DataSource = d;
```

Comment: I have 3 columns in my grid. Can I have a 3 dimensional list?

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to bind to dictionary you can try this using linq where foreach KeyValuePair you will create a Anonymous Type and convert to a list like so:

Assuming your datagridview is called dataGridView1:

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d.Add("1", "test1");
d.Add("2", "test2");
dataGridView1.DataSource = (from entry in d
                            orderby entry.Key
                            select new{entry.Key,entry.Value}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is perfect answer.

Comment: I have bound my grid to a dictionary using your code but even though the dictionary contains data, the grid disappears at run time. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

Old question but since I just stumbled across it, maybe somebody else will too. Dictionaries know how to make themselves into lists, so this will do it:

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = myDictionary.ToList();
```

Comment: Worth mentioning you should add `using System.Linq` at the top of the page